# Create a signed file from the detached signature and the clear text file content

Tags: cryptography, openssl, java, digital-signature, .net

Assuming I have the following:

- data.txt
- data.ps7 (the **detached** signature)

Can I generate the bundled signed file ?

Any example would be great, using `C#`, `Java` or `openssl` or any other tool ?

Comment: The firs answer from here can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013953/how-to-verify-a-file-and-a-p7s-detached-signature-with-openssl